# Using commands in cron

Tags: linux, cron, command

I am trying to use cron on my debian11 VM to create a folder with todays date on system reboot if it does not already exist, this is the line I have used.

```
@reboot /usr/bin/mkdir -p /home/bin/data/"$(date '+%Y%m%d')"
```

This work from the terminal, and after looking online I understand the issue is that cron is not ran like a shell, and that I could solve this problem by packaging this line inside a .sh file. I'm ok with this solution but in the interest of simplicity and learning, how would I rewrite this line so it would run from cron successfully?

Comment: Try a backslash before each `%`.

Comment: Yes thats solved it thanks! The backslash acts as an escape character, but why is this needed when it has been specified that a command will follow (the $")?

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you an explanation. I just know that's the way it gets parsed. We'll have to wait together and see if someone clever comes along...

Comment: From  `crontab` man page: "The sixth field of a line in a crontab entry is a string that shall be executed by sh at the specified times. A <percent-sign> character in this field shall be translated to a <newline>.  Any character preceded by a  <back‐slash>  (including  the  '%')  shall cause that character to be treated literally. Only the first line (up to a '%' or end-of-line) of the command field shall be executed by the command interpreter. The other lines shall be made available to the command as standard input."  The '%' are converted to newlines before the shell quotes are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape **percent-signs (%)** in your command with **backslash (\)** character:

```bash
@reboot /usr/bin/mkdir -p /home/bin/data/"$(date '+\%Y\%m\%d')"
```

Refer to [crontab(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab):

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run. The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile. Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

Comment: Please refrain from answering common duplicates; simply leave a comment pointing to one of the many existing questions about this problem.